# Binary Classification Model training in CoreML

Tags: ios, coreml

I have just started exploring CoreML and was wondering if there is a way to train a Binary Classification Model using the same.

Please provide me any references or examples as I am a ML noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core ML doesn't offer any APIs for building or training models. It works with models you've already trained elsewhere (Keras, Caffe, etc) to perform whatever prediction or classification task you built the model for. See [Apple's Core ML docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml) for info on how to convert a model for use with Core ML.

Answer (score 1):

Core ML offers building and training models as of macOS 10.14 (Mojave).  In XCode you can train models in various ways.

I don't believe they currently support a binary classifier, but if you can build an image set of X and NOT X you could emulate such.

Apple's Docs:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/create_ml/creating_an_image_classifier_model